# Python: White Spaces in File are not Being Removed

Tags: python, newline, whitespace

I am reading in a text file that has a number of entries, each in two parts: header and body.  When I open the input file in Notepad++, I see a CR and a LF at the end of each line.  When I run this file through my script, these are not being removed by the string stripping functions in Python.

The code I am using is below.  In my attempts to troubleshoot the issue here, I have gone so far as join lines that are first converted to unicode, have stripped out '\n', in addition to application of the generic lstrip() and rstrip()...so, complete overkill, yet the line endings remain unmodified.    If I print to an outfile, and open in Notepad++, I still see at the end of each line a CR and LF.

```
    with open (f, 'r') as data:  
           for line in data:
                 if 'WORD' in line:
                     f_out.write('\n' + line) ##by adding the return it now prints as needed.
                 else:
                     line = line.strip()
                     f_out.write(line)
```

Per request, the input basically looks like this:

```
entry title1 path=[742:0-740] CR LF
LINE1 CR LF
LINE2 CR LF
entry title2 path=[742:0-740] CR LF
LINE1 CR LF
LINE2 CR LF
entry title3 path=[742:0-740] CR LF
LINE1 CR LF
LINE2 CR LF
```

Comment: can u update the file in ur post

Comment: Pardon?  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: how ur input file look like

Comment: Try doing `f = open(filepath).read(); print "%r" %f`. You may need to split around \r\n, not \n

Comment: also print `ord()` for last character from line. e.g. `ord(line[-1])`

Comment: @Forager...first...I can't use a function that reads in all the lines at once, as the file is 30GB.  If I use x = open(file.read()) or x = open(file.readlines()) my computer all but crashes.  However, to test your idea out, I just ran the script on a subset of the infile...all that it did was change the result from >>>LINE to >>>L (new line) >>>I (on and on).

Comment: Stick a comma at the end: `print '>>>%s' % (line,),`

Comment: After tinkering around, it is 'working' well enough with the modifications shown in the code block...it's at least now writing titles on one line and body as continuous until the next title.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `next` (just naming a built-in function, not calling it) is a no-op.  Maybe you mean `continue`?  Innocuous here, anyway.

Next, your `line =` right hand side is beautiful in a grotesque way.  Just

```
line = line.strip()
```

will be equivalent and much more readable.

Lastly, `print` by default adds a line-end itself.  Best is to

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

(make `print` work as a function, as it always should have, and now does in Python 3 -- and you can have that enhancement in Python 2.7 too, "importing it from the future" as above!-), and then

```
print('>>>', line, end='')
```

The `end=''` part ensures that `print` adds no line-end afterwards (you can get that effect with old-fashioned "print as a statement" too, but the function kind works much better).

Comment: When skipping a line, I thought it was appropriate to use 'next'.  As for the other bit...my point is that no matter how many ways I ask for the line to be stripped of white space and joined to the  next line (assuming it doesn't have the specified word in it), it is not happening.  It should string them together, not print the '>>>>' before each line.  I have confirmed by printing to file that the white spaces are not being removed, and the input is the output.

Comment: @user3814464, "once again with sentiment": `print` is what is explicitly adding the `>>>` and implicitly adding the line-end.  Just `std.sysout.write(line)` after stripping it if you want to ensure it's just passed on to standard output unadulterated (you'll need to `import sys` at the top of your module, of course).

Comment: It's not the print statement that I care about so much as the fact that the white spaces are present in the body of the text, when it needs to be continuous until the next entry.  
After tinkering around, the closest to 'working' that I've got...and it will work for my purposes...is to modify the code as shown in the post.

Answer (score 0):

what i got from your explanation, that you wanto remove CR LF from every line

```
with open('file') as f, open('outfile', 'w') as f2:
     for x in f:
         x = x.strip()
         f2.write(x + '\n')
```

Comment: He means `\r\n` (carriage return, line feed) not literal `CR LF`.

Comment: *She* ;P ... though we can go gender neutral with "ze".